# Why doesn't Table work for list of pure functions?

Tags: list-manipulation, pure-function

I wrote a function

```
InversionF[f__] := Table[Function[x, 1 - ff[x]], {ff, {f}}]
```

I was thinking that for list of functions, it will create list of modified functions.

For one function it works:

```
InversionF[#^2 &]
```

gives

```
Function[y$, 1 - (#1^2 &)[y$]]
```

But for two functions it doesn't:

```
InversionF[#^2 &, #^3 &]
```

gives

```
{Function[x, 1 - ff[x]], Function[x, 1 - ff[x]]}
```

Although in first case I was expecting list of 1 element, which doesn't happen.

Why?

**UPDATE**

After restarting kernel, results became consistent but still not desired:

```
{Function[x, 1 - ff[x]]}
{Function[x, 1 - ff[x]], Function[x, 1 - ff[x]]}
```

Comment: Perhaps you have old definitions hanging around. Try restarting the kernel.

Comment: I found it didn't work for me even with just one function. Including `With` seemed to give me something sensible, though: `InversionF[f__] := Table[With[{g = ff}, 1 - g[#] &], {ff, {f}}]`... for reasons which baffle me.

Comment: @aardvark2012 any explanation for this?

Comment: So, following the linked topic: `InversionF[f__] :=
 Table[With[{ff = ff}, Function[x, 1 - ff[x]]], {ff, {f}}]`. If you disagree with closing, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

`Function` has attribute `HoldAll` so everything inside of it is held unless you call the function. You need to evaluate `ff` away from `Function` and substitute:

```
InversionF[f__] := Table[Function[x, 1 - #[x]] &[ff], {ff, {f}}]
```

Maybe also call `ff` outside Function:

```
InversionF[f__] := Block[{x}, Table[Function[x, 1 - #] &[ff[x]], {ff, {f}}]]
```

Alternatively:

```
InversionF2[f__] := Fold[MapAt[#2, #, {All, -1}] &, {f}, {1 - # &, Evaluate}]
InversionF2[#^2 &, Function[x, x^3]]
```

> {1 - #1^2 &, Function[x, 1 - x^3]}

Comment: This won't give a list of pure functions, which I want.

Comment: @Dims like the edit?